# DirectoryInfo MoveTo will failed If add new file to source folder

Tags: directory, windows-explorer, directoryinfo

**Steps to reproduce this issue:**

1. Create a Source folder and Target folder, c:\test\Source,
   c:\test\Target;
2. Create a sub-folder(TS-123456) under source folder and create some sub-folders and files in
   this sub-folder. It means, will be some sub-folders and files in this path **c:\test\Source\TS-123456**
3. Don't close windows explorer, just navigate to other path and don't
   make source folder open.
4. Run below code in a console or a form application:

```
try
{
    string sourcePath = @"c:\test\Source\TS-123456";
    string targetPath = @"c:\test\Target\TS-123456";
    DirectoryInfo drinfo = new DirectoryInfo(sourcePath);
    drinfo.MoveTo(targetPath);
    MessageBox.show("Move successful.")
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.show(ex.Message);
}
```

5. Error will occur "**Access to the path 'c:\test\Source\TS-123456**' is
   denied."
6. If I close all the opened folder and run the code again, all is
   fine. But if I add/delete a file under the source folder **c:\test\Source\TS-123456** and not close
   folder, just navigate from source folder to other folder then run
   the code, it will failure again.

Comment: Try this code with another drive like d:\

Comment: Try to use takeown and icacls commands to get the control of the directory.